# Polymer Project is slow to load

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, styling

The site has a nice theme. However the site slow to load even on googles serves. Is there anyway to speed polymer initial load time. Also it has loads of http request, can you reduce this?

Comment: Which site are you talking about? Is this about Stack Overflow itself?

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/

Comment: It about two seconds. But on my server it about three and I can't seem to use Google servers to just the polymer components for me.

Comment: This is about web development. What stack overflow is about (or at least what It advertises it self about) polymer is a element framework.

Comment: Have you looked at vulcanizing? It's a polymer tool that concats your templates into one (or several) files, to reduce the number of requests and speed up loading time.
[Vulcanize on GitHub](https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize)

Comment: Yeah. But I can't seem to install it using npm

Comment: Has any one posted a combined template. That can be download somewhere. Or how to u install and use valcanizing?

Comment: What browser are you currently using? The http://www.polymer-project.org/ website is still running on Polymer 0.5, which is slow on virtually any browser except Chrome.

Comment: Is there any solution besides vulcanize?

Comment: I am running polymer 0.5. Is polymer 1 faster? I can't seem to download the zip from the website when I choose my elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/).  It includes a build process to minimize resource loading, including [Vulcanize](https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize).

Comment: Have all the elements be combined?

Comment: The build process included in the kit will combine only the elements you use in your project using the Vulcanize program.

Comment: How do you use the vulcanize software?

Comment: You should be able to just run the `gulp` command.  https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/README.md

Comment: It is included in the Polymer Starter kit, and is used to build the system for production, among other things.

Comment: Do you need to install it

Comment: It will get installed if you follow the instructions for installing the Polymer Starter Kit.

Comment: Can you install it on Linux, windows and Mac?

Comment: It's a node.js application, so it should run on any OS that can run node.js, yes.

Comment: Sorry, I am novice. How do you run that?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/ once installed you will have the `node` and `npm` commands available.  Then you can run the commands in the Polymer Starter Kit's installation instructions at https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit?hl=en#install-dependencies

Comment: So surely, if i am installing the program onto my computer. It would matter what operating system i am running.

Comment: As you'll see on the Node Downloads page (https://nodejs.org/download/) they have an installer available for all of the common operating systems.  Since gulp, grunt, bower, and polyserve all run on node, they will all also run on any OS that node supports.